# Raspberry Pi2 IoT no HDMI output

Tags: hdmi, windows-10-iot-core

I have had Win 10 IoT Core running on a Raspberry Pi2, it was working fine, I had ported across my signage software, and all good, then the hdmi port stopped working ? my monitor just says no output, and goes into sleep mode. the Pi is running as I can assess it via the web portal, I can still deploy my application to it, and it says its running, but nothing been displayed.

I know that when using Linux there is a config file that you can modify, but what do you do with windows version ?

Comment: did you try reformatting it? It doesn't take long. You'll then be sure to know if it's a hardware or software issue.

Comment: yes, I tried it a couple with the official release, and then also installed the latest windows insider version, both the same.. boots up but not hdmi output ??

Comment: If you *did* reformat the card, ie apply the original image to the SD card, you have a hardware error. Hopefully the cables aren't connected securely, or the monitor is set to the wrong input (eg DVI or VGA).

Answer (score 0):

you have the configuration file for Windows too. check in the root of SD card. refer https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5851. You can try setting (this forces the board to use DVI mode instead of HDMI) 
hdmi_group=2                # forces DVI timing to be used

It might also be due to low power input to the RP2, which could cause HTMI to not work. Try using USB3 or 1.5A~2.0A/ 5V adapter.

Ensure that you are running headed mode and not switched to headless by mistake. Details here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/HeadlessMode.htm
he display.

Comment: I am using a 5v adapter, so I would assume there was enough power to output via the hdmi, I will check the settings file though.

Comment: figured out the issue? @Racing57